# Error while Adding buttons dynamically to Screen in ScreenManager Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to add buttons dynamicaly to screen. I have the following error when I run the app. Please help me resolve the issue.

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File "main.py", line 174, in
>   
>        screenManager.add_widget( HomeScreen( name = 'homeScreen' ) )    File "main.py", line 162, in **init**
>        self.add_widget(btn)    File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py",
>   line 111, in add_widget
>        pos=self._trigger_layout,  AttributeError: 'HomeScreen' object has no attribute '_trigger_layout'

Here is my main.py

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for i in range(80):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size=(90, 90), size_hint=(None, None))
            self.add_widget(btn)


# Screen Manager
screenManager = ScreenManager( transition = FadeTransition() )

# Add all screens to screen manager
#screenManager.add_widget( UsernameScreen( name = 'usernameScreen' ) )
#screenManager.add_widget( PasswordScreen( name = 'passwordScreen' ) )
#screenManager.add_widget( LevelTwoScreen( name = 'levelTwoScreen' ) )
#screenManager.add_widget( LevelTwoScreen( name = 'levelThreeScreen' ) )

screenManager.add_widget( HomeScreen( name = 'homeScreen' ) )

class ThreeLevelAuthApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return screenManager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ThreeLevelAuthApp().run()
```

kivy file

```
<HomeScreen>:
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 400, 400
        pos_hint: { 'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.5 }   
        do_scroll_x: False

    GridLayout:
        cols: 6
        padding: 20
        spacing: 20
        size_hint: None, None
        width: 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with `__init__`:

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for i in range(80):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size=(90, 90), size_hint=(None, None))
            self.add_widget(btn)
```

although this looks fine and is called when you make an instance, there's one basic thing missing - `super()`. You need `super()` to initialize the `Screen` first, so that it has all the required variables and methods that make it a class with real behavior and therefore makes you able to actually *inherit* the behavior.

Note that the `Screen` itself is a [`RelativeLayout`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html) and you'll need to handle additional stuff such as positioning and/or sizing if you won't use a layout that does that for you.

```
import random
class HomeScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HomeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(80):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size=(90, 90),
                         size_hint=(None, None),
                         pos=[random.randint(0,500), random.randint(0,500)])
            self.add_widget(btn)
```

Comment: Oh I've made a silly mistake. Thanks anyways. Its works fine now.